# "The system cannot find the file specified" for .out and .in extensions

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have a `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` like this (commentor asked to see entire code) to test some training page:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("inputFile.in"));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("inputFile.out")));

        int N = Integer.parseInt(bf.readLine());

        int[] dayCount = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; //Line 19

        int day = 0;
        for (int year = 1990; year < 1990 + N; year++) {
            for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
                if (month == 2) {
                    if (year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)) {
                        dayCount[(day + 13) % 7]++;
                        day += 29;
                    } else {    
                        dayCount[(day + 13) % 7]++;
                        day += 28;
                    }
                } 
                else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
                    dayCount[(day + 13) % 7]++;
                    day += 30;
                }
                else {
                    dayCount[(day + 13) % 7]++;
                    day += 31;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            if (i < 6)
                pw.print(dayCount[(i + 6) % 7] + " ");
            else
                pw.print(dayCount[(i + 6) % 7]);
        }
        pw.println();
        pw.close();
    }
```

I'm currently using VS Code, and when I ran the code, there was a pop-up (which I don't know how to reproduce) that said something along the lines of "The Marketplace has an extension that helps with the .out file extension." I looked in the extensions and then Googled and couldn't find an extension for `.in` and `.out` files. The reason I want one is because of the error which is thrown, even though I have the files created in the current working directory. This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: inputFile.in (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:212)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:154)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:109)
        at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:60)
        at iotests.iotests.main(ioTests.java:19)
```

I have commented line 19 above.

Comment: What is "the same folder"? The working directory?

Comment: Yes, the current working directory.

Comment: Do you mean where your class files are?

Comment: All of the abovementioned files are in the same directory.

Comment: I've compiled a simple program with this in it, and there are no problems. Are both inputfile.in and outputfile.out in the same directory, which is the working directory?

Comment: Also, please edit your question to include your entire example code. The includes must be included. And it would be nice for you to highlight line 19.

Comment: Yes, they're both in the same directory, the working directory, with the code in question.

Comment: Can you add on your question a screenshot of the file structure showing the files you mention? Also how are you running your code. it makes a difference from where you run your code as well.

Comment: I think I've explained the situation well enough. They are all in the working directory. I'm running the code from VS Code by clicking the "run" button atop `main`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your filename extension is strange, VSCode don't know which program can open it, so, it just hint you to find some program in the marketPlace to open it, just that. so, stop use the name of 'inputFile.in', 'inputFile.out', '.in', '.out' is the 
filename extensions, just '.txt'.